# Построение графиков функций и диаграмм

Tags: android, graphics

Привет.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие-нибудь туториалы или уроки, или расскажите, как строить графики и диаграммы, на русском. Ничего не могу найти в обучение себе по этому вопросу.

Comment: http://android-helper.com.ua/diagram/

Comment: недоступен сайт, да и траффик воровать нехорошо. там только ссылка была на исходный материал:
http://www.mobilab.ru/androiddev/achartengineforandroid.html